# Static method with mutable parameter thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a method

```
public static Person updatePersonId (Person person)
{
    // If the ID of the person reaches the maximum ID in our predefined range in configuration then reset the ID from the start otherwise it will cross the range we defined.
    if (person.getNewID ().longValue () == person.getLastPossibleID ().longValue ())
    {
        person.setNewID (person.getFirstID ());
    }

    // add 1 to Old ID to get new ID
    person.setNewID (person.getNewID + 1);

    return person;
}
```

I use hibernate to update it into database.

As you can see, I can't have more than one person in database with same `ID` (as we always add 1 to its previous ID).

Now the problem is, when I run my application concurrently, i.e. two transactions at same time, the ID assigned to person become duplicate sometimes e.g.

```
Database row

PersonID        PersonName

  1                  Bob
  2                  Robert
  2                  Daniel
```

Is the method i created, not thread safe ? Shall I add Synchronized keyword ?

Comment: Is my method not thread safe ? Shall I add Synchronized keyword ? NO Use DB sequences

Comment: @ScaryWombat, OP needs a cycling sequence.

Comment: But folks, can we do this without sequence ? And is my method not thread safe ? Is concurrency issue causing the duplicate ID apparently ?

Comment: `synchronized` will help for a single server, but won't scale to multiple instances. The correct approach is to use your database's atomicity guarantees.

Comment: mysql> ALTER TABLE myTable DROP id;
mysql> ALTER TABLE myTable
    -> ADD id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST,
    -> ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);

Comment: Thanks a heap! I will go for sequence then, but why does this method behave in thread-unsafe manner ? Do both transactions go in this code and get same ID somehow ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Will this SQL work in MS SQL server too ?

Comment: look at CREATE SEQUENCE .... CYCLE

Comment: Question, if I use sequence, not synchronizing the code, what if a transaction rolls back, there will be gaps in ID then. What if I have to ensure there are no gaps in ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this method is not threadsafe. As, two threads may reach to this line at sametime :-

```
person.setNewID (bnkPrb.getNewID + 1);
```

However syncronizing whole method will slow downthe codes, so take lock on only this line :-

public static Person updatePersonId (Person person)
{
    // If the ID of the person reaches the maximum ID in our predefined range in configuration then reset the ID from the start otherwise it will cross the range we defined

```
if (person.getNewID ().longValue () == person.getLastPossibleID ().longValue ())
{
    person.setNewID (person.getFirstID ());
}

// add 1 to Old ID to get new ID
syuncronized(this){
person.setNewID (bnkPrb.getNewID + 1);
}


return person;
}
```

However , best approach to have automincremented column or sequence at database side.

Comment: Thanks a heap. I now understand :)

Comment: Question, if I use sequence, not synchronizing the code, what if a transaction rolls back, there will be gaps in ID then. What if I have to ensure there are no gaps in ID.

Comment: Do you really need it because what ever approach you take , it is hindering the performance. Since you next action will have to wait till first completes. Even for syncronize you will need to syncronize whole method.

Comment: Right, it summarizes to that using sequence is best approach for performance reasons too.